# Opentok php server sdk, session and token not working

Tags: php, session, opentok

I need help for my Php server in opentok
this is my online website that i created

[mrsvideocall.bugs3.com/Engine.php](http://mrsvideocall.bugs3.com/Engine.php)

the url above gives you session and token

it has output session id and token but..
when i tried that output. the token and the session is not connecting

if you want to try
you can use my apikey and api secret this was just my trial account

api key : 45007972

api secret: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

try it. .it wont work

I dont know why.

this the code inside my php file. .is there anything wrong?

```
<?php
require "vendor/autoload.php";

use OpenTok\OpenTok;
use OpenTok\Session;
use OpenTok\Role; 
use OpenTok\MediaMode;

$API_KEY = "45007972";
$API_SECRET = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$opentok = new OpenTok($API_KEY, $API_SECRET);

// Create a session that attempts to use peer-to-peer streaming:
$session = $opentok->createSession();
$session = $opentok->createSession(array('mediaMode' => MediaMode::ROUTED ));
// Store this sessionId in the database for later use
echo $sessionId = $session->getSessionId();

// Generate a Token from just a sessionId (fetched from a database)
$token = $opentok->generateToken($sessionId);
// Generate a Token by calling the method on the Session (returned from createSession)
$token = $session->generateToken();

// Set some options in a token
echo $token = $session->generateToken(array(
'role' => Role::PUBLISHER,
'expireTime' => time()+(7 * 24 * 60 * 60), // in one week
'data' => 'name=Eleo'
));
```

if i just make session and token at dashboard it was working
but when i tried the result of my token and session generator it does not work
it has result but not working

Comment: Do not share your API Secret publicly, it is supposed to be a secret. I suggest that you stop using that API Key and generate a new one (by creating a new project in your TokBox Dashboard), now that the information was leaked.

Comment: Don't worry this just my trial and error account, I have another account that using for my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried the `sessionId` and `token` generated at your URL and they worked fine to connect. One caveat was that you also echo-ed a literal `\n` between the two values so I had to separate them. If you are having trouble connecting to the session, could you please share what error you are seeing and what client side code you have used?

Also, please read through the comments in the code you copy/pasted. You are actually generating 2 sessions and 3 tokens, but only outputting one of each, so you are unnecessarily doing extra work.

Comment: thanks for the info I already solve the problem. but thanks for the information about. my unnecessarily extra work